# Laravel Localization Language Switcher using currentRouteName pass argument

Tags: laravel-5, localization

I am having an issue with language switcher, when trying to execute a route with more than one parameter

I get following error message

```
    Missing required parameters for [Route: client.edit] [URI: {language}/client/{id}/edit].
```

in the header having an switcher code Route::currentRouteName()

```
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),'en') }}">EN</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),'ar') }}">AR</a></li>
          </ul>
```

I tried below code, it is not working

```
            <?php if(isset(request()->id)) { ?>
                <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),'en',request()->id) }}">EN</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),'ar',request()->id) }}">AR</a></li>             
            <?php } else {  ?>
            <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),'en') }}">EN</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(),'ar') }}">AR</a></li>
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have such kind of question due to every time when we use some routes, where have to send 1 and more parameters (I'm not talking about `language`) like `{id}`, `{category}` or something else, for example in your route: `/client/{id}/edit` - this kind of situation can be greatly passed but with out native multi-language implementation.

By truth, I've tried to use several variations with Middleware, ServiceProviders and else, but, the best way that I've understand is to use ready-made solution with support and going forward to reach dev. goals.

That's why I recommend you to use [this package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization) (**mcamara/laravel-localization**). They have already made cool functionality like route localization, standard support of many countries and some features that could be useful in the future.

Also, you will have to edit you current scripts to remove old made-localization by yourself or someone else and follow the instructions. I hope you will enjoy!